# Selecting events from events TABLE by date field?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table called **events** with 5 fields. Among those fields I have the **eventDate** field (date type field) in which I keep the date when the event will take place.

I made a dropdown with options to select from the **events** table.
1. All events (contains just the events from today and from the future, excluding those from the past)
2. Events this week
3. Events next week
4. Events next month

Can smbd help me with the SELECT statements for this, in MYSQL?

Comment: All these are different queries?

Comment: by 'this week' do you mean in the next 7 days, or between now and sunday?

Comment: Have you tried using the DATE functions of MySQL?: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Your query-1 could have something like: `WHERE CURRENT_DATE() <= eventDate`

Comment: By this week I mean what's left from today till Sunday (included) By next week I mean from next Monday till next Sunday By this month I mean what's left from this month Since I have a dropdown with options I want a select statement for each. I trying the date functions right now but i'm on a deadline and this site is way faster than me.

Comment: eventDate >= CURDATE() ORDER BY eventData. Thank you ypercube this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function x_week_range($date) {
                $ts = strtotime($date);
                $start = (date('w', $ts) == 0) ? $ts : strtotime('last sunday', $ts);
                return array(date('Y-m-d', $start),
                                         date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next saturday', $start)));
        }


        //all events


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate>='".date("Y-m-d")."' ";
        echo $sql."<br />";


        //current week 

        list($start_date, $end_date) = x_week_range(date("Y-m-d"));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate>='$start_date' AND eventDate<'$end_date'";
        echo $sql."<br />";


        //next week 
        $nextweek  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+7, date("Y"));
        $nextweek_day =  date("Y-m-d",$nextweek);


        list($start_date, $end_date) = x_week_range($nextweek_day);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate>='$start_date' AND eventDate<'$end_date'";
        echo $sql."<br />";

        //next month
        $m = date("m");
        $y = date("Y");

        $start_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$m+1,1,$y));
        $end_date = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$m+2,1-1,$y));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate>='$start_date' AND eventDate<'$end_date'";
        echo $sql."<br />";
```

Comment: ok, implemented and tested this, works perfectly. Thank you very much **g.b.1981**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the today date and all other dates with php and convert them to sql format.
In php:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');  
$today= mktime();
$dateSQL=date('Y-m-d',$today);  
$weekBegin=$today;  
while (date('w',=$weekBegin)!=0){  
$weekBegin=$weekBegin-24*60*60;  
}

1. SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate>='$today'
2. SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventDate>='$weekBegin' AND eventDate<'$weekBeginPlus7'
```

and so on.